# SQL Query select first if there are more value

Tags: sql, double, rows

I have the following sql query, it can happen that the value `PMLB.LAGERORT` has multiple values, then the row is displayed multiple times. I read and tried different approaches with cross apply, limit, and group by, but didnt got it working. If I try to `GROUP BY PFSP.KOMPONENTEN_ARTIKEL_NR` the error is

> Die PFAK.KD_VORGANGS_NR-Spalte ist in der Auswahlliste ungültig, da
>   sie nicht in einer Aggregatfunktion und nicht in der GROUP BY-Klausel
>   enthalten ist.

```
SELECT 
    PFSP.KOMPONENTEN_ARTIKEL_NR, 
    PFAK.KD_VORGANGS_NR, 
    PFSP.BEZEICHNUNG_1, 
    PFSP.BEZEICHNUNG_2, 
    PFAK.ZEICHNUNGS_DIN_NR, 
    PFAK.BEZEICHNUNG_1, 
    PFAK.AUFTRAGSENDE, 
    PFSP.BESCHAFFUNGSKENNER, 
    PFSP.BESTANDSKONTO_NR, 
    PFSP.BEREITSTELLUNGSART, 
    PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ, 
    PEKP.BESTAETIGTER_TERMIN, 
    RFSP.DECKER_SEGMENT, 
    PFSP.ENTNAHME_TERMIN_GRE, 
    PEKP.BESTAETIGUNGS_DATUM, 
    PFSP.RUECKMELDE_STATUS, 
    PFSP.ZEICHNUNGS_DIN_NR, 
    PFSP.ENTNAHME_MENGE, 
    PMLB.LAGERORT, 
    PEKP.VORGANGS_ART, 
    PFSP.ENTNAHME_MENGE_IST
FROM   
    PFAK 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PFSP 
        ON (PFAK.RUECKMELDE_NR=PFSP.RUECKMELDE_NR) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PEKP 
        ON (PFSP.BESTELL_NR=PEKP.VORGANGS_NR) 
        AND (PFSP.BESTELL_POS_NR=PEKP.VORGANGS_POS_NR) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RFSP 
        ON (PFSP.RUECKMELDE_NR=RFSP.RUECKMELDE_NR) 
        AND (PFSP.RUECKMELDE_POSITIONS_NR=RFSP.RUECKMELDE_POSITIONS_NR) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PMLB 
        ON PFSP.KOMPONENTEN_ARTIKEL_NR=PMLB.ARTIKEL_NR
WHERE  
    PFAK.KD_VORGANGS_NR=N'250-001969' 
    AND PFSP.BESCHAFFUNGSKENNER=N'F' 
    AND  NOT (
        PFSP.BESTANDSKONTO_NR=N'311000' 
        OR PFSP.BESTANDSKONTO_NR=N'312000' 
        OR PFSP.BESTANDSKONTO_NR=N'319000'
    ) 
    AND PFSP.RUECKMELDE_STATUS<>8 
    AND (
        PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ=2 
        AND PEKP.VORGANGS_ART=N'BE' 
        OR PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ<>2
    )
```

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: (1) I formatted your (big) query. Formatting is an important thing, it greatly improves the readability of SQL code. Please consider doing it yourself next time before posting. (2) Throwing this big query on SO without much information about the underlying table structures, you cannot really expect sensible answers. I would recommend that you narrow the problem to something that can be described with less code and provide associated sample data, and expected results.

Comment: sorry for badly formatting, I just copied from crystal report. will use minimal example next time. row_number() looks good, I fiddled a round and I am quite close and I think I am able to get it working with a customized query. but can not use it for crystal report, because it generate the query. the hope was that there is a way to simply add some code behind the query, but edit the whole query structure is not an option. thank you very much anyway!